# django signal post_syncdb

Tags: django, django-models

I have the `post_syncdb` signal hooked and the handler is supposed to insert some records into my models. However, this poses a problem because during testing, this conflicts with the records in my fixtures. I read that for model signals, they have an argument called  `raw`. Is there a similar kw argument for `post_syncdb` to know that when it is actually `loaddata` running?

Comment: Is there any special reason not to use fixtures instead of `post_syncdb` handling?

Answer (score 0):

This might seem like a bit of a primitive answer, but its worth a try. What if you were to check sys.argv in your handler to see if its being run with 'loaddata'?

```
import sys
from django.db.models import signals

def syncdb_handler(**kwargs):
    if 'loaddata' in sys.argv:
        # proceed

signals.post_syncdb.connect(syncdb_handler)
```